# How to load 16 bytes of memory into a Rust __m128i?

Tags: rust, sse, simd, intrinsics

I am trying to load 16 bytes of memory into an `__m128i` type from the `std::arch` module:

```rust
#[cfg(all(target_arch = "x86_64", target_feature = "sse2"))]
use std::arch::x86_64::__m128i;

fn foo() {
    #[cfg(all(target_arch = "x86_64", target_feature = "sse2"))]
    use std::arch::x86_64::_mm_load_si128;

    unsafe {
        let mut f: [i8; 16] = [0; 16];
        f[0] = 5;
        f[1] = 66;
        let g = _mm_load_si128(f as *const __m128i);
    }
}

fn main() {
    foo();
}
```

My code results in an error:

```
error[E0605]: non-primitive cast: `[i8; 16]` as `*const __m128i`
  --> src/main.rs:12:32
   |
12 |         let g = _mm_load_si128(f as *const __m128i);
   |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ an `as` expression can only be used to convert between primitive types or to coerce to a specific trait object
```

It's not clear from the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/arch/x86_64/struct.__m128i.html) how one goes about using `_mm_load_si128` to load bytes from existing memory or an existing type. I want to be able to load bytes into `__m128i`  from some existing type via a load intrinsic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> via a load intrinsic

Intrinsics are the [functions listed in the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/arch/x86_64/index.html#functions). Your specific example of loading from memory is covered [by the examples in the module](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/arch/index.html#examples):

> ```
> let invec = _mm_loadu_si128(src.as_ptr() as *const _);
> ```

For your case:

```rust
let g = _mm_load_si128(f.as_ptr() as *const _);
```

See also:

- [`arch::x86_64::_mm_loadu_si128`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/arch/x86_64/fn._mm_loadu_si128.html)